# How to compare one value to a whole array?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
arr[0] = arr[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
}

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
   if (i==arr[i])
    cout <<"F";
   else
    cout <<"f";

}
return 0;
}
```

This program has to take an (integer), then print a name consists of upper-cases and lower-cases letters 'F','f'. The letters in the name are numbered from 1 to n. from 1 to n it will search if i-th number is in Fibonacci series it will print 'F' otherwise it will print 'f'. 

I.E input: 8 expected output: FFFfFffF (from 1 to n) My output:FFFfffff 
I tried to do that, but I'm stuck 5th loop iteration.

Comment: How are you stuck?  are you getting an error or something?  Is it not working as intended if not why not?

Comment: [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) should do the trick

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - looks like the initialization of first 2 entries of fibonnacci sequence to me

Comment: your code outputs "O" not "F" thats surely your mistake

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki and what if n is -57?

Comment: `cin >> n;
int arr[n];` is not valid C++, but VLA extension. use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @pm100 edited done.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, watching values of variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and **waiting** for somebody to inspect your code or *debug it for you*.

Comment: @Eddge It doesn't output the output that I'm supposed to get.

Comment: @JuckiHarry can you include what you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: @Eddge Okay, I added that.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm using codeblocks.

Comment: You check that `if (i==arr[i])` so if `Fib(42) == 42` whereas you want to know if `arr` contains value `i`.

Comment: CodeBlock is an IDE, not a compiler. You probably use gcc so use `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but for i = 5 arr[5] = 7 which leads it to else and prints 'f' although 5 is fibonacci.

Comment: `1 1 2 3 5 8 13`, so firstly, `arr[5] == 8`, and as I said, you should print `F` for `5` as it exists an index for which `arr[i] == 5` (`arr[4] == 5`).

Comment: @JuckiHarry `int n;cin >> n;int arr[n];` -- When oh when will `gcc` turn this stupid VLA flag **off** by default?  All it seems to do is make newbie programmers believe they're writing valid C++ code.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){ if (i==arr[i])` -- This is an out-of-bounds condition when `i == n` in that loop.  Arrays start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want to compare starting from index of 1, because it contains Fibonacci numbers, I will tell you how it works. if (1==1) ok print F, if (2==2) ok prints F, if (3==3) ok prints F, here if (4==5) print f, now the programs fails every check and go to else I want to fix this!!, because if (5==8) it will print f although "5" is a number in my array elements!!

Comment: @JuckiHarry -- Did you read the comment carefully?  On the last iteration, you are accessing `arr[i]`, which is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @JuckiHarry -- Also putting away the silly VLA games would show the error to you [as seen here](https://www.ideone.com/zzP3cb).  Note the `out_of_range` exception thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded this up quickly but it does the job. You should try to format your code properly (spaces and comments) as a start. If you're taking user input then you need to be really careful that they provide what you're expecting. In your code above I could pass in a negative number, string, or whatever I choose and the rest of your code would execute!

Your code also needs to begin looping on `i = 0` since the Fibonacci sequence is defined for this value too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

//Returns integer from user input
int user_input(void);

//Returns the 'nth' fibonacci number
int fib(int);

int main () {
    int n = user_input();
    char fib_arr[n];
    std::fill_n(fib_arr, n, 'f');
    int ith_fib = 0;
    //loop until either the 'ith' fib number exceeds our array size or i exceeds
    //array size.
    for (int i = 0; i < n && ith_fib < n; i++)
    {
        ith_fib = fib(i);
        fib_arr[ith_fib] = 'F';
    }
    fib_arr[n] = '\0';
    std::cout << fib_arr << std::endl;
    return 0;
} 

//Returns integer from user input
int user_input() 
{
    int int_input = 0;
    std::string str_input = "";
    bool is_valid_int = false;
    while(!is_valid_int) 
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a positive number." << std::endl;
        //copy user input into str_input
        getline(std::cin, str_input);
        //convert str_inpt into a string stream object
        std::stringstream input_stream(str_input);
        //test to see if input_stream is of integer type and even and greater than 2.
        if(input_stream >> int_input)
        {
            is_valid_int = true;
        }

    }
    std::cout << "you entered " << int_input << std::endl;

    return int_input;
}
//Returns the 'nth' fibonacci number
int fib(int n)
{

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n ==1)
    {
        return 1;
    } 
    else
    {
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As state in comment, your condition is wrong:

```
void fibo(int n) {
    std::vector<int> arr(n); // Vector instead of VLA.

    arr[0] = arr[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), i) != arr.end()) { // Does arr contains i
            std::cout << "F";
        } else {
            std::cout << "f";
        }
    }
}
```

You can even get rid of the array as fibo is increasing sequence:

```
void fibo(int n) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (i == b)
        {
            int c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
            std::cout <<"F";
        } else {
            std::cout <<"f";
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/7LIwI6)